# In knockout.js, is it possible to use a dynamic binding value?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

In knockout.js, is it possible to let the right-hand-side of a binding (the value of the binding) be dynamic? For example,

```
<input data-bind="value: dynamicBinding()"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
var vm = {
   dynamicBinding : function() {
       return "foo().bar";
   },
   foo : ko.observable({
       bar : ko.observable("hi");
   }
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
</script>
```

the result should be that the the `dynamicBinding` function is executed while applying the bindings and the resulting string is used as the binding. The input element should be bound to `foo().bar`, which is the observable with the value "hi".

If you wonder why I would want this, I am trying to render a dynamic table with knockout, where both the rows and the columns are observableArrays, and I want to allow the column definitions to contain the expression of the binding for that column. I.e., I want to be able to do this:

```
<table data-bind="foreach: data">
  <tr data-bind="foreach: $root.columns">
    <td data-bind="text: cellValueBinding()"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
var vm = {
   data: ko.mapping.fromJS([
     {title: "Brave New World", author: { name : "Aldous Huxley" },
     {title: "1984", author: { name : "George Orwell" },
     {title: "Pale Fire", author: { name : "Vladimir Nabokov" }]),
   columns: ko.observableArray([
     {header: "Title", cellValueBinding: function () { return "$parent.title"; }}, 
     {header: "Author", cellValueBinding: function () { return "$parent.author().name"; }}
   ])
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
</script>
```

As you can see from the example, the column definition knows how to extract the value from the data. The table markup itself is more or less a placeholder. But as far as I can tell, this does not work, due to the way knockout processes the bindings. Are there any other options available?

Thanks.

---

**Solution**: I ended up using Ilya's suggestion - I can let cellValueBinding be a function that accepts the row and column as arguments, and returns an observable. This technique is demonstrated [in this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/7vCNt/2/)

Comment: If you _absolutely_ wanted to dynamically execute that, you'd have to resort to using `with`/`eval` to do it.  There's nothing built-in to knockout to do that.

Comment: Well, alternatives are welcome. :) I'm pretty sure I could achieve the same pretty easily with templates (each column defines its own cell template), but it feels a little too heavy weight.

Comment: You might be interested in my table binding: https://github.com/mbest/knockout-table

Comment: @MichaelBest: Thanks for the tip! It looks like you have solved the problem of "arbitrary cell values" in the same way I intend to - by allowing dataItem to be a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ko.computed` for it.
Look on example
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7csh2/)
**EDIT**
In your second example, you can pass `$parent` value ti the function

```
<td data-bind="text: cellValueBinding($parent)"></td>
```

and in model

```
{header: "Title", cellValueBinding: function (parent) { return parent.title; }},
{header: "Author", cellValueBinding: function (parent) { return parent.author().name; }}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aqxh2/5/)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how it would work in my second example. I need the binding to be in the column definition. For a computed to work it would have to be context-sensitive. Specifically, it would have to be able to access the "$parent" context variable.

Comment: This might actually work. I expanded on your fiddle as I expected it wouldn't work with real observables (and two-way bindings such as value), but it seems OK: http://jsfiddle.net/7vCNt/2/ . I'm going to test this in my real code tomorrow. Thanks.